# C++: 2D Arrays; code not working properly. Usual student and marks array

Tags: c++, multidimensional-array

One column for student, and one column for marks.
I have researched a lot for this but still the code isnt working.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    string arr[2][2];

    for (int i=0; i<2; i++)
    {
        for (int j=0; j<2; j++)
        {
            cout<<"Enter name: "<<(i+1)<<endl;
            cin>>arr[i][0];
            cout<<"Enter marks: "<<(i+1)<<endl;
            cin>>arr[i][1];

        }

    }


    cout<<arr[0][0]<<"\t\t";
    cout<<arr[0][1]<<endl;
    cout<<arr[1][0]<<"\t\t";
    cout<<arr[1][1]<<endl;
    return 0;
}
```

When i enter data, i get to insert 8 elements instead of 4. It's a 2x2 table.

Comment: _'What is wrong here?'_ doesn't constitute an appropriate question on this site! Please refer to the [help center](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) what and how can be asked here!

Comment: sorry, im so tensed at not being able to do the homework..

Comment: You have two loops of two loops of two inputs. 2x2x2=8

Comment: Do you need to have multiple marks per student? ie. can `jhonny` have a mark for maths and english?

Answer (score 4):

Think about your double for loop. You are going:

```
i: 0
j: 0

i: 0
j: 1

i: 1
j: 0 etc..
```

Yes this is 4 but each time you take 2x user input.

Try this:

```
for (int i=0; i<2; i++)
{  
    cout<<"Enter name: "<<(i+1)<<endl;
    cin>>arr[i][0];
    cout<<"Enter marks: "<<(i+1)<<endl;
    cin>>arr[i][1];
}
```

I mean you are not even using `j` in the loop? As a fun addition, think about using a different type for your storage of user and mark. I think that you would be better off with a `map`:

```
std::map<string, int> gradeRegister;
for (int i=0; i<2; i++)
{  
    string name;
    int grade;
    cout << "Enter name " << i+1 << ": " << std::flush;
    cin >> name;
    cout << "Enter grade " << i+1 << ": " << std::flush;
    cin >> grade;
    gradeRegister[name] = grade;
}
```

Maps make a lot more sense in this situation because then you will have a unique name to grade, its easy to search and you can expand it to contain many more people much more easily. Take a look **[here](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/map/map/)** for more information.

Comment: Thanks...at last -_-, i changed the nested for loop to this:

for (int i=0, j=0; i<2, j<2; i++, j++)

Comment: But dont we have to use j here? Because it's a 2D array?

Comment: @Daimonz, Why? for what purpose do you need the j?

Comment: @Daimonz But you are never accessing anything with j? So obviously you dont need it. I think you are going to be better off dropping arrays, they dont really have a place in c++ especially when there are so many good stl types to use.

Comment: The `map<string, int>` only allows a 1:1 ratio between student and marks.  Maybe you meant `std::map<string, vector<int> >`?

Comment: @ThomasMatthews the OP doesn't seem to want multiple grades per person, but sure, if you wanted to expand it to multiple grades per student then that would be a good idea.

Comment: @Ben: What i thought i 'knew' is that for populating a 2D array, you should have 2 variables to use in a nested FOR loop.  Guess i was always wrong...this is frustrating having the wrong information..

Comment: @Daimonz Think about how you are accessing your 2D array, you are always just accessing 2 elements. So say you had N students you would loop through N times and always ask 2 questions so there is no need for the 2nd for loop. If you were accessing a picture though, say it was 800x600 and you wanted to access every pixel, then it would make sense to have: `for i = 0 to 800; for j = 0 to 600` so that you visited every pixel. This is the sort of 2d array you are thinking off, one with the possibility for variable size in both dimensions.

Answer (score 1):

Although you can ask for  values, a more user friendly method is to input all the marks for a single user before asking for all the marks for another user.
*(The following code assumes one student can have multiple marks and student names are unique)*:

```
#define MAXIMUM_STUDENTS 3
#define MAXIMUM_MARKS_PER_STUDENT 4

typedef std::vector<std::string> Marks_Container;
typedef std::map<std::string, Marks_Container> Registry_Container;
Registry_Container student_registry;

  for (int student = 0; student < MAXIMUM_STUDENTS; student++)
  {
    cout<<"Enter student name name: " << endl;
    std::string student_name;
    getline(cin, student_name);

    Marks_Container student_marks(MAXIMUM_MARKS_PER_STUDENT);
    for (int mark_index = 0;
         mark_index < MAXIMUM_MARKS_PER_STUDENT;
         ++mark_index)
    {
      cout << "Enter mark "
           << (mark_index + 1)
           << ": " << endl;
      std::string mark;
      getline(cin, mark);
      student_marks.push_back(mark);
    }
    student_registry[student_name] = student_marks;
  }
```

There is no reason to duplicate student names, which is the reason for the `std::map<name, marks>` structure.  The key field is the student name and the value field is a vector of marks.

Comment: Does he actually want more then one mark per student? +1 for the good inputs, i should have used getline.

Comment: @Ben:  The usual assignment involves more than one mark per student.

Comment: Cool, I have upvoted, hopefully he marks yours as correct if that's correct.

Comment: The syntax seems so advance for the OP I think, that this may not helpful at all for him.

Comment: @mr5, yes it is lol, but still, i'll try to figure out whats the meaning of the syntax they used...and thank you all once again Thomas Matthews and Ben. Appreciate it.